# How to exclude lib.dom.d.ts from tsconfig?

Tags: typescript

I've declared a class named Event:

```js
class Event {}
```

...and Typescript complains about a duplicate identifier:

```
Duplicate identifier 'Event'.ts(2300)
lib.dom.d.ts(4870, 11): 'Event' was also declared here.
lib.dom.d.ts(4912, 13): and here
```

How can I exclude types in lib.dom.d.ts from being imported automatically?

Comment: Event is essentially a global class (in [Node](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#class-event) and in [the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)). Even if you could override it and name your own class `Event`, it's probably not a good idea. You'll likely continue to run into conflicts with the global Event class.

Comment: Voting to close, as this is not reproducible. An attempt to define the Event class in a typescript authored program is also, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug), a programmer induced bug, as it causes a compiler error.

Comment: Your comment that a 'programmer induced bug' that 'causes a compiler error' is nonsensical @jD3V.  The point of the post was to override the behavior of the compiler to disable the error.  Whether that is a good idea or not depends on my use case.

Comment: @JΛYDΞV I don't get it...don't declarations in an ES Module shadow identifiers of the same name in global scope?